Code runner won't run in terminal even after changing the setting
I'm trying to setup c++ on vscode on mac. I'm using code runner to do it but by default its set to use the output tab rather than terminal, which you can't input anything into, but when I change the setting to run in terminal, it still runs in output.
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,


Where have you made this change?

in settings.json

'If you set "code-runner.runInTerminal", the code will run in built-in terminal. But if the file is untitled or running code snippet of selection, it is still in Output Window.' Found with google, maybe it's relevant.

the file is neither untitled or running a snippet of code, I've looked online and I haven't found anything that mentions anything like this

do you have powerSHell installed? It might be problem with python assuming that terminal is powerShell

no, I even reinstalled vscode and only installed the nesecessary extensions and it still won't run in terminal
